# Numbering row in oracle 11g

Tags: select, oracle11g

I need to have a temporary column that displays 1 to 10 when I select the top 10 customers that spent the most.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY c.cust_name) "No.", c.cust_name "Customer Name", SUM(r.payment_amount) "Total Spent"
    FROM customer c, reservation r
    WHERE c.cust_id = r.cust_id
    GROUP BY c.cust_name
    ORDER BY 3 DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 10;
```

But the query will give me output like this:

```
       No. Customer Name                  Total Spent
---------- ------------------------------ -----------
       112 Romola Bice                           7095
        15 Beck Boxhill                          6600
       123 Taite Tradewell                       6600
       108 Port Risdall                          6600
       105 Paxon Rendell                         6600
        33 Daphne Stilwell                       6600
        57 Gretel Davidsen                       6200
        95 Mylo Bengoechea                       6200
        78 Kare Goodayle                         6200
        65 Hilton McCluney                       6200
```

This is what I want:

```
       No. Customer Name                  Total Spent
---------- ------------------------------ -----------
       1   Romola Bice                           7095
       2   Beck Boxhill                          6600
       3   Taite Tradewell                       6600
       4   Port Risdall                          6600
       5   Paxon Rendell                         6600
       6   Daphne Stilwell                       6600
       7   Gretel Davidsen                       6200
       8   Mylo Bengoechea                       6200
       9   Kare Goodayle                         6200
       10  Hilton McCluney                       6200
```

I when replace `row_number() OVER (ORDER BY c.cust_name)` to `rownum`, give me error: `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`.

Is there any way to achieve my desired output?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: google for "Top N query". this is what you are looking for. 
In this case you don't need row_numbe function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to select `rownum` in first select:

```
  SELECT ROWNUM "No.", Customer Name, Total Spent
  FROM (
      SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY c.cust_name) "No.", c.cust_name "Customer Name", SUM(r.payment_amount) "Total Spent"
      FROM customer c, reservation r
      WHERE c.cust_id = r.cust_id
      GROUP BY c.cust_name
      ORDER BY 3 DESC
  )
  WHERE ROWNUM <= 10;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! There are some missing double quotes.
Customer Name --> "Customer Name"
Total Spent --> "Total Spent"